# Moving imageview with touch event

Tags: android, layout, touch, imageview

I just want a simple thing. I have a `imageview` and I can move it with touch

This is my code, I'm sorry if this wrong because I just tried it myself

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            status = StartDrag;
        } else if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            status = StopDrag;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (status == StartDrag) {
        params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX();
        params.topMargin = (int) event.getY();
        img.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Can you show me the right way please?

Comment: So, you tried it your way, and what was the result? Is this code working or not?

Comment: work althought i dont touch the image :(

Answer (score 26):

I have done this way:

```
private float xCoOrdinate, yCoOrdinate;
```

**onCreate()**:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xCoOrdinate = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                yCoOrdinate = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                view.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate).y(event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
       return true;
    }
});
```

**Done**

Comment: how to move only inside bounds that the view doesn't get out of bounds

Comment: @AmeerHamza did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Let me Answer down.

Comment: Dragging view going out of the screen. Any solution pls let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

`onTouch` events for dragging views works perfect for child views of `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout`.

Here is an example:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            {
                x = event.getX();
                                    y = event.getY();
                dx = x-myView.getX();
                dy = y-myView.getY();
            }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            {
                myView.setX(event.getX()-dx);
                myView.setY(event.getY()-dy);
            }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            {
                //your stuff
            }
        return true;
}
```

Now what `dx` and `dy` does is, on `ACTION_DOWN` it records where you have touched on the view, and gets difference from left (x) and top (y) of the view, to maintain those margins during `ACTION_MOVE`.

Return of touch event has to be `true` if you are attending it.

**Update : For API 8**

In case of API 8, The `getX()` and `getY()` methods are not giving correct results, so what you can use is `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` methods.

Example :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams par;
float dx=0,dy=0,x=0,y=0;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
        {
            parms = (LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams();
            par = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getLayoutParams();
            dx = event.getRawX() - parms.leftMargin;
            dy = event.getRawY() - parms.topMargin;
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        {
            x = event.getRawX();
            y = event.getRawY();
            parms.leftMargin = (int) (x-dx);
            parms.topMargin = (int) (y - dy);
            myView.setLayoutParams(parms);
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
        {

        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, so you have to do it different way on older APIs, check updated example.

Comment: btw i have a quetion, what is the different on touch and ontouchevent?

Comment: onTouchEvent is method of View class, you can implement it if you are creating custom view, wheres onTouch is method of listener to handle touch events elsewhere, its like onTouchEvent's MotionEvent is passed to onTouch method if listener is set. You can also use it for passing events from one view to another, like if a MotionEvent recorded from myView1 can be forwarded to myView2.onTouchEvent(event).

Comment: I tested this code. The ImageView flickers during moving and has very inaccurate position

Comment: This method makes the image flicker while moving. Any other solution to this?

Comment: @Enigma which method are you using for getting touch coordinates ? `getX()` or `getRawX()` ? Use `getRawX()` if its flickering in `getX()` ( same applies for Y ).

Comment: Thanks Apurv. Let me try. I also found this answer very helpful. It ideally handles almost everything - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624671/application-with-a-lot-of-images-that-could-be-dragged-around/29624808#29624808

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            StickerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.shsticker_relativeLayout1);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
            layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            final ImageView view = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            view.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            view.setImageResource(shstickerBaseAdaptor.shstickerImage[arg2]);
            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                            .getWidth();
                    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                            .getHeight();

                    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Toast.makeText(ImageEditingClass.this,
                                "hii rma jee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                        if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                            x_cord = windowwidth;
                        }
                        if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                            y_cord = windowheight;
                        }

                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 15;

                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord -100;

                        layoutParams.rightMargin = x_cord - 50;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = x_cord - 50;
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            // setText(++ViewGenerate + " hii this new");

            StickerRelativeLayout.addView(view, layoutParams);
            // }
            Toast.makeText(ImageEditingClass.this, "you click" + arg2,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  move your image in  any direction  you need  to pint out the direction
  you should  follow the following step
 step -1
            float dx = 0, dy = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 0, dz = 0, dw = 0; 
              { these  you four   coordinate }

```
public void StickerPopulate(){
    LinerLayoutInfate.removeAllViews();

    shstickerBaseAdaptor = new ShstickerBaseAdaptor(getApplicationContext());
    View shstickerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shareimage,
            null);
    Gallery shsticker_gallery = (Gallery) shstickerView
            .findViewById(R.id.shsticker_gallery);
    shsticker_gallery.setAdapter(new ShstickerBaseAdaptor(
            ImageEditingClass.this));

    shsticker_gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            StickerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.shsticker_relativeLayout1);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
            layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            final ImageView crossBtn = new ImageView(
                    getApplicationContext());
            crossBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross);

            crossBtn.setMaxWidth(300);
            crossBtn.setMaxHeight(200);
            crossBtn.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            final ImageView view = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            view.setImageResource(shstickerBaseAdaptor.shstickerImage[arg2]);

            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                            .getWidth();

                    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                            .getHeight();

                    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        dx = event.getRawX() - layoutParams.leftMargin;
                        dy = event.getRawY() - layoutParams.topMargin;
                        dz = event.getRawX() - layoutParams.bottomMargin;
                        dw = event.getRawX() - layoutParams.rightMargin;

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                .getLayoutParams();

                        x = event.getRawX();
                        y = event.getRawY();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) (x - dx);

                        layoutParams.topMargin = (int) (y - dy);
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = (int) (z - dz);
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = (int) (w - dw);

                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            StickerRelativeLayout.addView(crossBtn, layoutParams);

            StickerRelativeLayout.addView(view, layoutParams);
            // }
            Toast.makeText(ImageEditingClass.this, "you click" + arg2,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
    LinerLayoutInfate.addView(shstickerView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows to drag and move a view.

```
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;

public class DragMove<T extends View> implements OnTouchListener
{
    private final  T view;
    private int leftOffset;
    private int topOffset;

    public DragMove(T dragable)
    {
        this.view = dragable;
        this.view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View p1, MotionEvent event)
    {
        /*
        public static int pxFromDp(double dp, View v)
        {
            Activity context = (Activity)v.getContext();
            return pxFromDp(dp, context);
        }

        public static int pxFromDp(double dp, Activity context)
        {
            float logicalDensity = getDensity(context);
            int px = (int) Math.round(dp * logicalDensity);
            return px;
        }
        */

        int x = GuiUtils.pxFromDp(event.getRawX(), view);
        int y = GuiUtils.pxFromDp(event.getRawY(), view);

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                {
                    // calculates offset to current coordinate,
                    // keeps position relative (from jumping) during move
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams parms = view.getLayoutParams();
                    // e.g. = x - params.leftMargin
                    leftOffset = x - Layout.readLeftMargin(parms);
                    topOffset = y - Layout.readTopMargin(parms);
                }
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                {
                    // adjust by touch position retaining touch
                    // offset at start
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams parms = view.getLayoutParams();
                    // e.g params.leftMargin = x - leftOffset
                    Layout.writeLeftMargin(parms, x - leftOffset);
                    Layout.writeTopMargin(parms, y - topOffset);
                    view.setLayoutParams(parms);
                }
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```