# Application with a lot of images that could be dragged around

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm creating an app which could basically select a set of images from the app's gallery, put it on screen and then resize, move drag or anything on the image.

Should I be using a simple FrameLayout/RelativeLayout with ImageViews and OnTouchListener on ImageViews or should I use a canvas and have it all handled manually? Can someone show me some direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of this lib  https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views

```
<com.thuytrinh.android.collageviewsdemo.CollageView
        android:id="@+id/collageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/green" />
```